# Bitwise masking

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Assuming an environment where `long int` is a 64-bit type, suppose I have an `long int = 0x0123456789ABCDEF`  and I want to get the byte that represents 89. Would this line work?

```
n = (n >> (b << 3)) & 0xFF;
```

where n is the `long int` and b is the byte I want. So `b` would be 3 and shifting it left 3 would multiply it by 8 changing it into a byte so shifting should look like this 0x0123456789. Is using & 0xFF the right way to mask to get the last byte?

Comment: There is no guarantee a `long` can hold that value. Please see [ask], provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct approach. This [online example on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/fyj98o) prints `89` as expected.

Comment: I saw you used long long n instead long int n. Is there any difference?

Comment: @JMei `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide. [On some platforms like Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models), `long` is only 32 bits wide.